# can't generate keyhash facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I've tried to implement the following SO answer: [Facebook Android Generate Key Hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12405323/2835541).

> 13) Again copy following code and paste
>
> `openssl base64 -in debug_sha.txt > debug_base64.txt`

When I try point 13 (above), I get the error:

```
openssl.exe has stopped working.
```

I've also tried using:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

but I get the error:

```
Illegal option: Alami.android\debug.keystore keytool -list [OPTION]...
```

Comment: do you have openSSL downloaded in the system?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28408600/2015538

Comment: yes i have openssl in the system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can directly create it programatically.**

**Just add this code in your onCreate method.**

```
try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "com.package.mypackage", 
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
```

**And you will get keyhash in Log.**

Comment: i don't understood with this method -_-

Comment: @ArifAlami Have you tried to generate keyhash with this method ?

Comment: @ArifAlami Just try this code as i have suggested it will give you keyhash to add in your facebook project.

Comment: when the app running, i got a problem when i login to FB. it say "Invalid Scopes: publish_steam. this message is only shown to developers. users of your app will ignore these permision if present. plaese read the documentation for valid permision at /developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permisions"

Answer (score 0):

try to download openssl from [here](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) than execute

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore YOUR_PATH_HERE/.android/debug.keystore | PATH_TO_BIN_FOLDER_OF_SSL_DIRECTORY_IN_C:/openssl.exe sha1 -binary | PATH_TO_BIN_FOLDER_OF_SSL_DIRECTORY_IN_C:/openssl.exe base64
```